# Buchones with more UNIDAD action

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

Which Buchons provide more missions where you'd have to deal with UNIDAD, rather than the cartel ?

I'm replaying the game and would like to play against UNIDAD more, rather than the Cartel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was only one Buchone for either LaPlaga or Ramon Feliz that was pure UNIDAD. The rest was all Cartel.

What gave me what I was looking for and was quite a lot more difficult, was the Fallen Ghosts DLC. Almost entirely UNIDAD and harder